# Manage Category broken In Magento

Tags: magento, backend, categories

In the Magento admin panel I clicked the tab "Manage Categories", then the manage category section displayed.

But the previously added categories are not showing there.

And I can't add any any new categories.

Then I clicked on the "RESET" button and I got an error message like the one below:

[image]

What is this?

What is the problem here?

Is there any solution for this?

And one more thing, when I loaded 'manage categories' I got an error in fire bug too:

```
TypeError: hash.__properties is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

if (current.length == hash.__properties.length)

deprecation.js (line 339)

TypeError: hash.__properties is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

if (current.length == hash.__properties.length)

deprecation.js (line 339)

TypeError: hash.__properties is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

if (current.length == hash.__properties.length)

deprecation.js (line 339)

TypeError: hash.__properties is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

if (current.length == hash.__properties.length)

deprecation.js (line 339)

TypeError: hash.__properties is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

if (current.length == hash.__properties.length)

deprecation.js (line 339)

TypeError: Ext.tree.TreePanel is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

Ext.tree.TreePanel.prototype.getChecked = function(node){

ext-tr...kbox.js (line 5)

TypeError: Ext.UpdateManager is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

Ext.UpdateManager.defaults.loadScripts = false;

/bc/in...565cdc/ (line 76)

TypeError: Fieldset is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

Fieldset.addToPrefix(1);

/bc/in...565cdc/ (line 83)

TypeError: Ext.tree.TreePanel is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

Ext.tree.TreePanel.Enhanced = function(el, config)

/bc/in...565cdc/ (line 618)

TypeError: hash.__properties is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

if (current.length == hash.__properties.length)

deprecation.js (line 339)

ReferenceError: updateTopButtonToolbarToggle is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

updateTopButtonToolbarToggle();
```

The when I clicked on the "add root category" or "add sub category" then I got an error in fire bug:

```
TypeError: tree is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

tree.addNodeTo = tree.currentNodeId;

/bc/in...565cdc/ (line 947)

TypeError: tree is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

tree.addNodeTo = tree.currentNodeId;

/bc/in...565cdc/ (line 947)

TypeError: tree is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

tree.currentNodeId = tree.root.id;

/bc/in...565cdc/ (line 945)

TypeError: tree is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

tree.currentNodeId = tree.root.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened because of Magento Inline Translation Bug. Just go to `System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Translate Inline` and choose "No" for "Enabled for Admin" setting.

Comment: ,the "Enabled for Admin" ,"Enabled for Frontend" already set as "No".

Comment: yes did that but no effect..the errors in fire bug displays same as described above

Comment: After what action (installed module, etc.) did it happen?

Comment: the action is iam trying to move the magento site from live server to locahost.Everything done successfully.But i got this error in admin panel.

Comment: I cant to view any categories created on admin panel ,but its viewed in fronend.

Comment: there have some categories created.but no one is displayed

Comment: you should debug or just try to reinstall Magento. Also you can use firebug to check response from server. And on server you can use `var_dump` or `Mage::log` (require logging enabled) for checking vars.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14394/discussion-between-mariya-davis-and-serjio)